# How can I get rid of the extra white space of figures?

Tags: figure-placement

My codes are:

```tex
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn,margin=1mm]{revtex4-2} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{overpic}
    
%%%%%%
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure*}
    %\centering
    \begin{overpic}[width=3in]{tree.jpg}\put(6,68){(a)}\end{overpic}
    \hspace{-3mm}
    \begin{overpic}[width=3in]{tree.jpg}\put(6,68){(b)}\end{overpic}   
    \begin{overpic}[width=3in]{tree.jpg}\put(6,68){(c)}\end{overpic}
    \hspace{-3mm}
    \begin{overpic}[width=3in]{tree.jpg}\put(6,68){(d)}\end{overpic}\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

And this is what I get
[image]

I want to get rid of the useless white edge, I have tried the {standlone}, but something is wrong, so what can I do?
The tree picture is: [image]

Comment: you are forcing the images to be 3in wide `[width=3in]` so naturally if the page is wider than 6in you get white space

Comment: also don't do `\hspace{-3mm}` which i am guessing is trying to compensate for the inter-word space between the images, just omit the space by commenting out the end of lines with `%`

Comment: It appears that overpic is adding the space internally (bug).  If you use `\includegraphics` by itself, the space goes away.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the pictures occupy the whole text width, tell LaTeX so.

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{overpic}

\usepackage{showframe}

%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}

\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{tree.jpg}\put(6,68){(a)}\end{overpic}%
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{tree.jpg}\put(6,68){(b)}\end{overpic}

\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{tree.jpg}\put(6,68){(c)}\end{overpic}%
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{tree.jpg}\put(6,68){(d)}\end{overpic}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` package is loaded just to show the margins of the text block. Don't load it in the final version of your document.

Note that the option `margin=1mm` is invalid, so I removed it.

I also removed `\hspace{-3mm}`: the `%` at the end of the line prevents the space you were trying to cancel out. The second row of picture should be separated by a blank line as in the code above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, it still have extra white space.

Comment: @karry Where? Not if you look at the picture.

Answer (score 0):

This replaces `overpic` with `\llap`.  I'm not sure if I got the scale the same as overpic.

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.005\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}\llap{% overlap pictures
\makebox[0.5\textwidth][l]{\put(6,68){(a)}}\makebox[0.5\textwidth][l]{\put(6,68){(b)}}}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}\llap{% overlap pictures
\makebox[0.5\textwidth][l]{\put(6,68){(c)}}\makebox[0.5\textwidth][l]{\put(6,68){(d)}}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```